# Would anyone be interested in joining a related StackExchange website?

Tags: discussion

I'm posting here because on another site, people were fine with advertising related sites on meta (see [this question](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192/is-it-ok-to-advertise-related-area51-sites-on-meta) on the German Language and Usage meta). If anyone here has objections, feel free to have this question deleted.

Anyway, I've proposed a slightly related site on area 51 about [college admissions](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/36082/college-admissions?referrer=c5Gl1KSm6M_5fokvC2vYNw2), which a good deal of parents will be concerned with at some point. If anyone is interested in the proposal, it would be great if you could follow it to track its progress and later join the site when it goes into beta.

Answer (score 2):

I'm fine with linking to relevant content between SE sites, and even linking to sites outside the SE network. I don't see any harm in it -- if people aren't interested, they'll just not click the link.

The proposal seems rather *localized* to me, since it appears to revolve around a rather US-centric concept of "college admissions." Admission to college varies wildly between countries, so I'm not sure exactly how the proposed site would get enough content to stay alive - but it might be a very deep topic and I just can't tell.

So personally, I wouldn't be interested in joining that site, but you're welcome to advertise it to those who are interested.

Comment: I'm not particularly worried that there will be a lack of questions, since some online communities (eg. http://talk.collegeconfidential.com/) are hugely active just with people discussing college admissions and related issues: choosing colleges, paying for college (scholarships, need-based aid), standardized tests, and so on. There's plenty of things to be asked. Most other countries tend to have simpler processes than the US for applying to colleges, so there wouldn't be nearly as many questions for other countries.